# Continuous tasks in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

i'am using nodejs with express for my webapp and i need to to run continuously 
some code which checks if some data change and then update my mongodb.

How can i easily create a background process which runs the whole time together with the main task? So that the background task/process can inform the main task.

What i have tried already:

- to solve this problem with a "setInterval" Function in the main process --> I works with no problem but think its not a good idea because it blocks the node event loop
- Use child processes -> i could not found a good tutorial on them --> is there a easier method, perhaps a library which could help me?
- some background worker libraries -->But do heavy-load tasks on the a child-process and finish but i need to do the work all the time

Update:

**Final Solution**:

**UpdateEvent.js**:

```
var events = require('events');

function Updater(time) {
    this.time = time;
    this.array = [
        {number: 1},
        {number: 2}
    ];
    var that;
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);

    this.init = function()
    {
        that = this;
        console.log("Contructor");
        //Start interval
        setInterval(that.run,that.time);
    };

    this.run = function()
    {
        that.array.forEach(function (item) {
           if(item.number === 2)
           {
               that.emit('Event');
           }
        });
    };
}

Updater.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;

module.exports = Updater;
```

and then the code that uses it:

**server.js**:

```
var Updater = require('./UpdaterEvent');

var u = new Updater(10000);
u.init();
u.on('Event',function () {
   console.log("Event catched!");
});
```

I followed the tutorial at:
http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/

Comment: Is that background task CPU heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you export your `Updater` constructor function:

```
exports.Updater = Updater;
```

When you require it, you do

```
var Updater = require('./UpdaterEvent');
```

and then try to run:

```
var u = new Updater(10000);
```

The problem is that you do not expose the function itself, but an object with a property called `Updater` which contains the function. Hence you either have to export it using

```
module.exports = Updater;
```

or you have to require it using:

```
var Updater = require('./UpdaterEvent').Updater;
```

Either way, then calling `new Updater()` will work. At the moment, you try to initialize a new object by calling an object instead of a constructor function, hence the error message:

> TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Thanks for the tip with "module.exports = Updater;" now i can instantiate it but me problem now is that the this.run function cannot access the this.array variable i get a " Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined" why?

Comment: You don't use `this.array`, you only use `array`. Apart from that, once you've fixed that your call to `this.emit` will fail, due to the new binding of `this` within the callback. Please make yourself familiar with the various contexts of `this` and especially the commonly used line `var that = this;`.

Comment: Now i edited my code to the working final solution! Thats for the help, now i have a very elegant solution.

Comment: i have now a strange issue that after some time the interval is not firing any more!? Why could it be?

Comment: You should open a new question for this, as it's not related to above, and otherwise the discussion in these comments gets lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Events and EventEmitter](http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/)

You could use child-process you don't really need to since JS is asynchronous.  Just create a function for your background process and pass it your eventEmitter object.  You can use setInterval or a while(true) loop to continuously check for the data change.  When the data changes, call eventEmitter.emit('someEvent'); which will trigger a function in your main task to update your mongoDB.